# How does the TCP/IP Socket in MongoDB client/server connection work?

Tags: mongodb, sockets, tcp, handshake, peer-wire-protocol

According to the Documentation for [Mongo Wire Protocol](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Wire+Protocol):

> Clients should connect to the database with a regular TCP/IP socket. There is no connection handshake.

This sounds confusing to me. Clients connect to server with a regular TCP/IP socket. In this case, how could a connection be established without the three way handshake? Am i missing anything important?

Thanks for any comment in advance!

Comment: They must mean no Mongo-wire-protocol-specific handshake.

Comment: Ok, I see. So then it can be understood as follows: the first time to communicate with the database, a connection with regular TCP/IP socket is established, which does surely need the three way handshake. After the connection is open, all communications (querying/saving/updating etc) happen directly (without handshake), until the connection is closed, which again requires handshake (four steps in this case).